# XML Stylesheet href doesn't work with absolute URL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to figure out why the first XML is previewed in IE but not the second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="d:\Dropbox\Public\style.xsl"?>
```

So that one works, but not this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.org/style.xsl"?>
```

Can you not use absolute paths in the href value? I want everyone to be able to preview the XML without the need of sending the XSL file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the actual cause of your problem, but something that *might* cause it is the `standalone="yes"` in your XML declaration.

If your file needs *any* external file for *any* reason (including DTDs, schemas... and stylesheets), there should be either nothing or `standalone="no"`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, any other ideas?